# How to send register email from Jhipster Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, service, jhipster

I've developed an application using jhipster. I've setted application-dev.yml file with this information

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
    include:
      - swagger
      # Uncomment to activate TLS for the dev profile
      - tls
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: **********@gmail.com
    password: ****************
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    properties.mail.smtp:
            auth: true
            starttls.enable: true
            ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
```

an it can't build success with error

```
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 62, column 10:
          tls: true
             ^
```

Please help me fix this if you (anyone) have time. Thank you so much!

Comment: Make sure that the `yaml` is properly indented. Try validating at : http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: Maybe you did insert some non ASCII characters above the failing line in username or password values that we can't see because you replaced them by `*` characters in your question.

Comment: Username is my gmail and password is my google application password (16 characters). I used it for the php's sendmail application and it worked properly. Please help me if you have free time.